# Log.d displayed nothing in Logcat using eclipse on miui phone

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, miui

I try to use Log.d to display some message to Logcat in Eclipse but find that it shows nothing. I believe the Logcat ability to show Log.d or not IS hardware/device dependent, that is becuase the phone I worked on is miui. There may be some kind of settings in the phone that I need to change in order that to work. This post discusses it.

```
Log.d("TAG", "can I see this in Logcat?");
```

Why I make the assertion is that after I disconnected the usb debugging cable from the phone and using an emulator instead. It shows the following dialog box for me to choose and it display something in the Logcat when run.

[image: Auto LogCat Monitor dialog box]

Comment: One task here is first to find out is there any way to show this Auto Monitor Logcat dialog box for any device

Comment: the above dialog box only appear when connect to emulator , but not with miui phones